# SQL Query Update Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

```
update invd.InvoiceDetail set invd.costprice=883.75
from InvoiceDetail invd
where saleDespatchDetailID = 5
```

I'm getting an error in this query:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid object name 'invd.InvoiceDetail'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you provided an alias you will reference the alias, so the code should be:

```
update invd
set invd.costprice=883.75
from InvoiceDetail invd
where invd.saleDespatchDetailID = 5
```

But since you are not joining the table with another table, you do not actually need the alias.

```
update InvoiceDetail
set costprice=883.75
where saleDespatchDetailID = 5
```

Comment: actually this is just a small part of my query, I join 3 tables to this query.. what ever your answer is correct. it works for me Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

you are not joining in your update so you could directly execute the basic `UPDATE` statement.

```
update InvoiceDetail 
set    costprice = 883.75
where  saleDespatchDetailID = 5
```

In my own way of writing `UPDATE` statement, I only use `FROM` if I'm joining a table on the update statement, like this below

```
UPDATE a
SET    a.ColumnName = 'a'
FROM   table1 a
       INNER JOIN table2 b
            ON a.PK = b.FK
WHERE  a.Column = 'xxx'
```